# What is the best way to keep track of versions of multiple micro services delivered as part of a software solution?

Tags: project-management, release-management, tools, tracking

We have an enterprise solution which consists of multiple components which are in turn comprised of micro services. We cater to both onprem and hosted models.
The challenge is to keep track of the GIT tag and version details of the components/services that are delivered to customers.
I am looking for a tool that would help track these and open to building one as well. I built a prototype on mvc but looking for something nimbler and easy to host.

Looking for abilities to be able to search for specific version or service. Also the customers might have several labs so a consolidated view will be very helpful.
Like I said, I built a prototype using mvc but would like a more nimble, open source tech stack (if there is no tool already) to maintain the data.
Also, was wondering if the same can be achieved through PowerApps or Sharepoint lists? The grid view/consolidated view along with search are my biggest requirements.

[image]

Comment: Voting to close this, as you seem to already have a general solution idea (a list or table with search and aggregation functionality) and are mainly looking for tools which is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak toward "best", but there are a couple tools that I've seen used or used myself.  One such solution that has been adopted by Spring Cloud, Ubuntu, and a number of other products is [Calendar Versioning](https://calver.org/) (CalVer)

Calendar Versioning works like this:

- The 4 digit year is the major version
- All other version markers are for a whole release
- This version is used collectively for a larger product, and individual components can have an independent version number

Example: `2021.0.1`

I've used Release Train numbering.  We break up our deliveries into consistently sized release trains, so internally we use `RT25` to version the collective microservices.  When we deliver to our customer, we simply alias the RT number with the customer's version number--who uses Semantic Versioning (SemVer), but with their own semantics of how to increment the numbers.  We do that because we've had cases where we thought the customer's semantics would apply for a different number, but they surprised us.

That said, our individual libraries and microservices have their independent version numbering, and the RT version (or CalVer) applies to the collective for a particular release.